# How to use an if-structure for finding out if ets table is empty

Tags: erlang, ets

I am new to Erlang. I have a project for school which uses an ets:table.
But before I want to get some data out of the ets:table, I want to use an if-structure for checking out the table if it isn't empty.

```
 if 
   ets:first(Cal) =/= '$end_of_table' ->
     Event = ets:first(Cal),
     {TimeAtStart, Ref} = Event,
     NowTime = now(),
     Ms = timer:now_diff(NowTime, TimeAtStart)div 1000
   end,
```

Now this gives me an error: Illegal guard expression.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

With friendly regards

Daan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` expect a guard sequence. so it fails. You could make the test before the if, and use the result, but with your code, when you get '$end_of_table', it will fails also since you have not `true` statement.

I recommend to use a case statement for your code:

```
case ets:first(Cal)  of
     '$end_of_table' ->
           {error,no_entry};
     {TimeAtStart, _Ref} ->
           {ok,timer:now_diff(now(), TimeAtStart)div 1000}
end,
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.
It works just fine.
I actually uses both solutions in my project, just for educational purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The illegal guard statement comes from calling the ets:first(Cal) function from within an if statement guard. so `if ets:first(Cal) =/= '$end_of_table' ->` is not going to compile correctly. Guard statements only have a small set of functions that can be used, [read about them here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80116).

Also if statements are a little different in Erlang vs. other languages. One clause at least **must** evaluate to true.  The [Documentation on if statements](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77103) explains this behavior, and how an error is thrown if no clause evaluates to true.

So moving the `ets:first(Cal)` outside of the if statement and adding a catch all true case to your code, should work:

```
Res = ets:first(Cal),
if 
  Res =/= '$end_of_table' ->
    Event = ets:first(Cal),
    {TimeAtStart, Ref} = Event,
    NowTime = now(),
    Ms = timer:now_diff(NowTime, TimeAtStart)div 1000;
  true -> ok %% you need a default clause
end,
```

However, if it was me doing my school project, I would try to use the ets:info function to check the size of the table, and do it inside of a case statement. Checkout the [Documentation on the ets:info function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#info-2), and [the case statement](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77168).

Just FYI: I don't think I have used an if statement the entire time I have been programming in Erlang.

Comment: I usually have one `if`-statement for every 5000 lines of Erlang code or so. `case` is much more common.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.
It works just fine.
I actually uses both solutions in my project, just for educational purpose.